# Buttons the same length as Input Type="text"

Tags: html, css

I have a Fiddle that shows my Problem : http://jsfiddle.net/ftud12ke/ .
You can see the Green `<div>` .It is set to `width:100%;` because it is inside my dark box,but actually i want the Green `<div>` to have the same width as my Text Input field and also the two Buttons (login,register) to be the same size as the text input field.

Hope someone can help me with this problem ;) I dont get it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to `.box-wrapper` (which is `block` by default):

```
.box-wrapper {  
   background-color:green;
   display: inline-block; //add
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftud12ke/1/)

Comment: @lolio Great glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved?